# Raspberry pi greyed out wifi networks

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, wifi

Why do some of the wifi networks appear greyed out ? 
These are usually the enterprise network. How can i connect to such networks using my raspberry pi , with raspbian OS.

Comment: Gather the connection details encryption scheme, passphrases etc. and configure the connection manually.

Comment: thanks steve ! it works now. seems like raspbian doesn't let one connect to entreprise wifi without manually setting it up. Thanks again !